# No internet with Firefox: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION failed

Tags: networking, lubuntu, firefox, internet

I'm new to `Lubuntu 20.04`, just installed it yesterday. When I turn on my laptop it connects to WiFi correctly and I tried pinging Google and it works fine, but when I open Firefox this error message appears
 `g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION failed` and cannot access any website

I found this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490871/lubuntu-g-is-dbus-connection

With an apparent fix, but I do not want to do things blindly. Can anyone please go a little deeper into what is going on with `sudo apt-get purge fcitx-module-dbus` they propose there?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

`fcitx-module-dbus` is a requirement of `fcitx-frontend-qt5` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/fcitx-frontend-qt5) which is itself a requirement of `lubuntu-desktop` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop)

Thus I would expect the consequence is the removal of your Lubuntu desktop (on *focal* or 20.04) and you're left without a GUI.

The consequence may not occur straight away, it may occur when the next clean up occurs (`sudo apt autoremove`).

I've not tested it, but that's what I'd expect would happen, so I'd look for another solution.

Comment: Note I've attempted to answer your question as written only. I've not encountered the error message you describe, and I would firstly look at what packages you have installed post-installation that may have created the issue.

Comment: FYI:  If interested, I didn't use the browser to get these results, but used a few commands `apt-cache rdepends` on my own system (which is *hirsute* not *focal*) and then confirmed using packages.ubuntu.com in *focal* for pasting here. If you hadn't installed many packages (my prior comment), I'd likely suggest filing a bug `ubuntu-bug firefox` at terminal so I/we can explore, or you could use Lubuntu's discourse so *devs* see it.  Responding here is okay too, just slower (currently I'd blame other packages you've added but didn't mention; if you didn't add any that is more concerning to me)

Comment: Indeed not many packages installed so far. I'll see how to fill the bug report, as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: So, update. The original problem is solved, sort of by chance. 
I just booted Lubuntu in the laptop. When I start Firefox from the Terminal the message still appears but I have internet connection.
Should I still report this if I do not know real symptoms of the error? 
It also contains a  **(firefox:1596): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL : numbers** 
Is it ok/safe to make those numbers public?

Comment: I don't know what numbers you're talking about, but they're likely memory addresses; which will be different next time you boot anyway; so I believe they are safe. GTK programs are very common; even on properly working programs (users don't normally see them as they end up in logs only; running from terminal lets you see them). If the problems has resolved itself, I'd not file a bug, but should it occur again, I'll provide the following on filing bugs https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  (the first is Lubuntu's, second is the main Ubuntu page)